# Develop Angular App in Sub-Directory

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

**Is there any way I can configure the `ng-serve` command to serve static html files at the root directory, and serve an angular app at a sub-directory?**

---

I'm developing an angular 2 app, and for SEO reasons I want to host the actual app in a sub directory while serving static pages from the root directory. Something like this

```
./
    About.html
    Home.html
    Contact.html
    /app
       app.html //Angular app goes here
```

I've found the `ng build --base-href <base>` which creates a production version of the angular app that can live in the `<base>` sub-directory, but this means I have to develop the angular app separately and then import the output into my final project. I'm hoping for an angualr-cli solution, but I'm open to any ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've realised, the `ng build --base-href <base>` option allows you to create a production build of your app that knows how to work properly from the `<base>` directory of your website. That's one part of the puzzle - configuring Angular to be able to run from a non-root folder of your server.

The second step is configuring your Angular CLI setup to put your build files in the correct location. Now, you can do this manually - have your ng-cli app in a completely separate folder and after you build it, copy the artifacts from the /dist folder of your Angular app into your website directory structure. This is the manual way of doing it. In this context, the items in the /dist folder of your angular app are basically static content from the point of view of a web server and can be treated as such.

But, another alternative is to look into your `angular-cli.json` and change the `apps[0].outDir` configuration option as needed. The `outDir` option specifies where to place the output of the `ng build` command. By default, it's set to `/dist`, but it can be changed to whatever you need it to be.

So, for eg, if i have the structure like this:

```
./public
    About.html
    Home.html
    Contact.html
    /app
       app.html //Angular app BUILD OUTPUT goes here
/angular-app  // Angular app source code
```

I can have my angular-app's `angular-cli.json` configured such that `outDir` is pointing to `../public/app`

that is, in angular-cli.json

```
app: [ {
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "../public/app",
  ......
} ]
```

Comment: Ah, I think I get the idea. I can develop the angular app itself in the `/angular-app` directory. Then, when I want to test the app in context of the greater sight I can build it to the proper directory, and run a node server to serve all the routes. Thanks for the help!