# how to deploy angular5 application to sub directory

Tags: angular, production-environment, ng-build

My angular application is hosted in server in which the application url is http://xyz.domain.in (Example Url). Now I created sub directory inside it to host another application. But when i try to access the path like http://xyz.domain.in/subfolder , getting this in console.

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'subfolder'

Base href of the application in subfolder is

```
<base href="./subfolder">
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Develop Angular App in Sub-Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742152/develop-angular-app-in-sub-directory)

Answer (score 42):

You have to specify the path of your subfolder when launching a build :

```
ng build --base-href=/subfolder/
```

Answer (score 10):

do not need to mention the subfolder name, if you are depolying at subfoler you need to mention only  href="./"

Comment: This seems to work, so to me this looks like a useful answer. **To the person who downvoted this:** please explain why an answer might not be a viable option in your opinion or tell the person who posted it what you think is missing in the comment section below the post.. do not just give it a random downvote.

Comment: This works for me too. Probably the best answer here. Thanks!

Comment: maybe the user could write a more complete answer, explaing that you have to change the <base href="/"> tag to <base href="./"> in index.html file, but yes, it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

build into subfolder:

```
ng build --prod --output-path="dist/subfolder" --deployUrl="subfolder/"
```

https://floyk.com/en/wall/status/BX

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `pathMatch` to your routes like so:

```
{path: 'url', component: YourComponent, pathMatch: 'subfolder'},
```

Comment: This would not solve the issue. The issue experienced is from serving multiple apps over a single domain and the angular app living in a subdirectory on the server. See answer below

Answer (score -1):

To properly setup an Angular app on a subdirectory:

1. Update the angular.json to include the `baseHref` property under the build options. ie:

```json
...
build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "baseHref": "/subdirectory1/subdirectory2",
```

2. Update the index.html base href:

```html
<base href="/subdirectory1/subdirectory2">
```

3. Ensure `useHash` is NOT set in your app routing module's `ExtraOption` (since the default is false)
4. Update image and style links. any absolute image links should be made relative

ex. FROM: `src="/assets/img/pic.jpg"` TO: `src="assets/img/pic.jpg"`

scss ex.

FROM: `background-image: url('/assets/img/pic.jpg`
TO: `background-image: url('../../../assets/img/pic.jpg`